# Wordpress - fail to install WPBakery Page Builder in Liquid on 2 servers served by Load balancer

Tags: wordpress

I try to install the WPBakery Page Builder within Liquid on 2 servers served by Load balancer.

Installation sometimes cracks, and sometimes I manage to skip to the next step and I got error 500.
Then I put these in wp-config.php to read the errors:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Then I reached step 3 "Import Content" but it produces so many errors, among others:

```
Required parameter $width follows optional parameter $attach_id in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MediionWp\wp-content\plugins\liquid_js_composer\include\helpers\helpers.php
```

or

```
(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MediionWp/wp-content/plugins/liquid_js_composer/js_composer.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

the file really doesn't exist in the path above.

Comment: `Required parameter $width follows optional parameter $attach_id in` is a deprecation notice and not an error: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.deprecated.php

Comment: Thanks, but it crashes my app.

Comment: that doesn't crash the app. The not found file crashes it most probably. Check the archive of your plugin and make sure the file is in there. If it is, upload the zip file manually and unzip it in the plugins folder, then go to the dashboard and activate it. What PHP version are you on?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to obtain it in order to deploy it to plugins folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I managed to solve it:

1. problem (Required parameter $width follows optional parameter $attach_id):

They wrote a function that accepts first optional parameters, then mandatory, which is strange, so instead of

```
function wpb_resize( $attach_id = null, $img_url = null, $width, $height, $crop = false )
```

I've put

```
function wpb_resize( $attach_id = null, $img_url = null, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false )
```

2. problem (No such file or directory)

I took a file `liquid_js_composer.php` from the same directory and copied it named as `js_composer.php` because I suspect they forgot to rename it (or referenced a wrong file name)

So far so good, haven't noticed any more problems yet.

Comment: There was one another thing I fixed: I got error at line 203 of \wp-content\plugins\liquid-wpbakery\include\classes\core\class-vc-manager.php; solution: turned private method __wakeup() into public.